# Handing of "JSON does not allow non-finite numbers" in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to do aggregation on a field using MAX function inside my index, the issue is when I do aggregation with group by it fails whenever I don't have that value inside of a time frame

```
POST /_opendistro/_sql
{
    "query": "SELECT date(timeStamp) time_unit, MAX(testField) test_field_alias  FROM my_index where orgId = 'xyz' and timeStamp <= '2020-07-04T23:59:59' and timeStamp >= '2020-07-01T00:00' group by  date(timeStamp) order by time_unit desc"
}
```

My index mapping is as given below

```
"mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "orgId" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "testField" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "null_value" : 0
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "type":"date"
        }
      }
```

When I try the above query I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "j_s_o_n_exception",
        "reason": "JSON does not allow non-finite numbers."
      }
    ],
    "type": "j_s_o_n_exception",
    "reason": "JSON does not allow non-finite numbers."
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I have understood this happens for time frames where I don't have the above-mentioned field in the documents in my index, SO I added `"null_value":0` to my mapping but still of no use.

Thing is I want to do aggregation using `MAX` function `grouped by` time scales if there is another approach that works, that's enough for me it doesn't have to be in SQL format only.

Comment: Could you please share the version of Elasticsearch in which you are facing this issue?

Comment: Its elastic version 7.4 opendistro